How to professionally tell colleagues on business trip their judgemental comments are unwelcome
I was recently on a business trip in the United States on behalf of my company. I am a manager and have been with my company for about 10 years.
I came home from a night social event at the bar with multiple colleagues at different levels (i.e: some below me on hierarchy and some above me). I had been drinking. A peer employee who also had been drinking, and in same division but different team as I, whom I had been dating went to my hotel and stayed in same hotel room as I for a night upon my invitation. Multiple colleagues coming back saw us as we on same floor of hotel. We both knew each other well, and neither had a conflict of interest that would make dating each other unethical or unprofessional.
Yet, in the morning, my other colleagues from previous night began to make judgemental and meddlesome comments such as spending the night with a peer colleague is indiscreet and shows lack of self discipline and is just unsuited for a business trip. I felt my colleagues comments were out of line and meddlesome in what is private time between two individuals. She and I are fine with our choice, and our choice to spend the night together did not affect the work we did on this company trip or bring the company into disrepute.
Is my perception that how I spend private time off the clock with a peer colleague on company sponsored trip none of my fellow colleagues concern?
How could I have professionally expressed to my other colleagues that their comments were unwelcome and I perceived them as intrusive and meddlesome?

Is the “i had been dating” going on for a while and was your relationship out in the open previous to this trip? Or is the perception of the night that you got drunk and “took advantage” of your colleague?

The latter. The comments were saying spending the night together in this context is indiscreet and shows poor self control. Neither of us were completely sober, having had about several drinks

The perception of this is probably very culturally dependent. Can you clarify what culture you and your colleagues come from? (Was this a domestic business trip within the US, or did you come from a very different place?) How close are you to those colleagues? (Would you normally chat with them about everyone's sex life? Or was them commenting on yours very much out of character?) Personally, coming from western/central EU, I would perceive colleagues who aren't my close friends commenting on my sex life as way more inappropriate (bordering on harrassment) than me having it in the first place.

@TooTea , I come from USA and this trip was domestic in the US. I am not personally close friends with these colleagues out of work and we do not discuss our dating lives. However,  we are friendly at work , think of bff. The colleagues came from eastern Europe and some from SE Asia

So they might not actually have known you were dating said coworker?

@Anthony.  How did the complainer know that you spent the night together? Typically these things happen a bit more discreetly. Did you make a public spectacle out of this and is that what the complainer may be objecting to?

@Hilmar, we all stayed at same hotel and folks who commented were on same floor as I and she. Everyone came back from bar at same time. They saw she and I enter  my room previous night and come out the next morning. Seeing what happened between us as normal and not worthy to mention, I said we stayed together and that's when meddling began

@Hilmar, apparently per some of my colleagues, private consensual conduct was a gross indiscretion...smh?

It seems that your problem isn't the comments but their opinion. Taking into account that having sex with a co-worker on a business trip can (but doesn't have to) legitimately be seen as indiscrete, your goal seems unreachable. Therefore: either accept their judgement or be more discrete.

Your "private time" ended when you (intentionally or not) made it public. Word gets around an office, this is one of the risks of dating a co-worker. You have other good answers so I'll leave it at that.

@spuck, what do you mean? I never bothered to tell my divisional colleagues as it's none of their concern whom I date. I did not market this , but neither am I ashamed of what happened.

@Anthony, I mean your entire group left the bar together and your coworkers saw the two of you enter the same hotel room. You are wasting your time trying to change their opinions or how they perceived that. No, it doesn't matter what they think. Why is it mattering to you what they think?

@Anthony, I knew a manager that dated a coworker from a different department. There was no conflict of interest there either, but often times, that coworker would get invited to our department's business trips and to our department's retreats, when she really had no business being there.
I'm not saying this is what happened in this case. But when dating a coworker, you need to be extremely cautious about giving off the the appearance of a conflict of interest, even if there is none to begin with.

It's not even about the co-worker. You'd get the same comments if you had a one night stand with a stranger, invited your girlfriend into the hotel or booked a hooker. Sex on a work trip is seen by a significant part of people as indiscrete. You should accept that what you are doing is not exactly "completely normal". It's not bad imho, but somewhat awkward imho. Others apparently agree.

"Judgemental" is one of the few words in the English language that is inherently self-referential.

The professional response is , "Noted; thank you for your concern." Then stop to think about whether they might not have been being judgemental but trying to warn you about the legitimate risks involved; answers have addressed that. Once you are aware of those, make a decision about how to balance risk vs. benefit. Their reaction (and management's reaction) is not something you can control. Your response to it is.


How could I have professionally expressed to my other colleagues that their comments were unwelcome and I perceived them as intrusive and meddlesome?

Don't, just ignore it - anything else is going to have a straight up Streisand Effect. You and your colleague did nothing wrong, but surely you aren't surprised by the reactions of the others? Workplaces are notoriously gossipy, and business trips only amplify that aspect because of the way that you get to see people out of their normal work environs etc. So two co-workers on a business trip deciding to enjoy some horizontal refreshment together overnight is like catnip to the office scuttlebutt, especially when there's some on-again/off-again backstory (assuming this is the same co-worker you've posted about previously).

Is my perception that how I spend private time off the clock with a peer colleague on company sponsored trip none of my fellow colleagues concern?

You're quite correct in that the overnight time is absolutely private time and you can (within reason and legality) do with it as you wish - but there is the fact that you're still where you are for business reasons, and that carries with it certain additional expectations of decorum and professionalism that don't apply to other off-the-clock time - e.g. it's fine to drink at a work social and get mildly inebriated but you probably shouldn't get blackout drunk doing body shots off Jeremy from accounting's six-pack.
Do I think there's anything wrong with two consenting adults who happen to be co-workers spending the night together? Not at all, but people are going to talk about it if they are aware of it and you need to be prepared for that. Don't fuel any drama and they'll have something else to talk about next week that has nothing to do with you.

worth noting that it would very much be on the table for the same coworkers to also make remarks even if the relationship was with someone not with the company also present at the bar; people talk and like to gossip, it's not outside the ordinary to make comments about the things people did while inebriated on a company night out.

Yes, this person is the same colleague in my previous questions. They saw I and she enter and exit my room together. I am surprised at their highly unwelcome comments as I expected them to turn a blind eye. Mixed layers of hierarchy present or that we all had been drinking heavily were immaterial imho

This might pragmatically be the best way to make them drop the topic, but by not setting clear boundaries, this approach also somewhat normalizes the (to me) wildly inappropriate and unprofessional behaviour of openly questioning someone else's private matters. You can't stop the coworkers gossiping among themselves, but that doesn't mean they should also be free to make the OP uncomfortable.


Is my perception that how I spend private time off the clock with a
peer colleague on company sponsored trip none of my fellow colleagues
concern?

It's your personal perception. You are free to have your own opinion about how wise it is to sleep with peers during business trips - as are your colleagues.
Some feel that business trips are solely for business. Others feel that it's free for all party time. Neither are right or wrong - they are just personal perceptions.

How could I have professionally expressed to my other colleagues that
their comments were unwelcome and I perceived them as intrusive and
meddlesome?

You can tell them bluntly that it's none of their business.
Or you can be more discreet while on business trips and avoid the comments altogether.

From your previous posts, it seems that your girlfriend is working in a different team, and you are not her manager because HR, you, and your girlfriend have agreed to this arrangement.
Is it possible that the coworkers, who made those comments to you, are not aware that you and your girlfriend are in a relationship and HR is aware of it ?  (If yes, then maybe, they were just trying to help you avoid potential trouble with HR.)
If your coworkers are not aware that you two are dating, then you just need to politely inform them that you and your girlfriend are in a relationship, and that HR is OK with it.
After that, everything should be fine.

Comments were not so much about dating, but about sleeping for the night in the same room. Apparently, they view it as crossing a decorum boundary. My view is that you see it, you know it, but never comment or judge upon private non work conduct between consenting adults

From what you've posted, you relationship seems perfectly appropriate and acceptable in the context of your employment. If it were me, I'd simply ignore this.
People have opinions about things. Sometimes those opinions are about you or your actions and behaviors. You don't have to entertain these opinions.
Someone may be of the opinion that the best way to cook eggs is to scramble them. I don't have to entertain, consider, or respond to that opinion if I disagree. I can simply ignore it.


Is my perception that how I spend private time off the clock with a
peer colleague on company sponsored trip none of my fellow colleagues
concern?

If your coworkers care about you, then it is their concern. In the US and other parts of the world there was/is the #MeToo Movement, and these colleagues just witnessed you and her spending a night together without any context.
Since they have no knowledge of your current relationship, they can and likely will assume the worst. Their intention may be trying to warn you about the nonexistent hazard you face if she turned around and claimed you forced yourself on her. This would result in not just the loss of your job, but also destruction of personal relationships, and possible lawsuits and court cases.
If you care about someone that is making a decision that could result in that level of bad, then yes, you should speak up and let them know, even if it comes off awkward or as meddling.

How could I have professionally expressed to my other colleagues that
their comments were unwelcome and I perceived them as intrusive and
meddlesome?

Though their actions were indeed intrusive and meddlesome, there is no need to address them directly. They likely were just as uncomfortable saying it as you were hearing it. As such, keep your response professional. If they have concerns in the future you want them to communicate those concerns to you first in private rather than gossiping about it in public behind your back:
Thank you for expressing your concern. (Her Name) and I have been in a relationship for some time now, and HR is already aware and has approved it. For now, we want to keep the relationship private, so we are not advertising that we are in a relationship.  In the future, if you see anything else that does not add up, do not hesitate to talk to me about it.

Yes, we both had been drinking and more than  a buzz. Will try to use this template , removing the last sentence. Somehow, per their cultural norms, what happened is a decorum breach. Smh...

The goal of the last sentence (which can be swapped with something else that meets your goals) has to do with a concept from Crew Resource Management (CRM) where you do not want to also accidentally squash other forms of questioning in the future that are desirable and could save you from trouble (or allow you to more quickly respond to a problem): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew_resource_management

This answer unnecessarily frames the Me Too movement as being about false claims.

@Michelle from the colleagues perspective they cannot know whether there was consent or not and, and therefore it is to their credit to communicate their concerns.

Nonexistent context of she and I being together for one night was deliberate because I saw no need to invite intrusion into a matter that simply doesn't concern my other colleagues. My colleagues are not and should not police morality...

@Anketam I agree with Michelle that your quickness to jump to false claims is problematic. If people were to have concerns, they would be concerned about her having consented and would approach her with those concerns—since sexual assault is far, far more common than falsely claiming to have been sexually assaulted.

@Anketam "from the colleagues perspective they cannot know whether there was consent or not and, [...]" And without consent "assuming the worst" is about false claim and not sexual assault?

So in short, your position is that any time two adults spend some private time together, it's okay for random bystanders to assume it was non-consensual until publicly proven otherwise?


Yet, in the morning, my other colleagues from previous night began to make judgemental and meddlesome comments such as spending the night with a peer colleague is indiscreet and shows lack of self discipline and is just unsuited for a business trip. I felt my colleagues comments were out of line and meddlesome in what is private time between two individuals. She and I are fine with our choice, and our choice to spend the night together did not affect the work we did on this company trip or bring the company into disrepute.

As some of the other comments have pointed out, you are free to make these choices as you will.  You keep pointing out that there is no company policy forbidding the behavior, blah, blah, blah ad infinitum.  But what you seem to miss in all of this is that while you are again free to choose, you are absolutely not free of the consequences of your choice.
Country singer Bonnie Raitt once recorded "Something To Talk About", and something to talk about is exactly what you have given your co-workers.  If you don't want the jeers, hushed conversations, and stare-downs, then you're going to have to be discreet.  You're not married to this coworker, and if you're unable to pause for a few nights to carry out your romantic liaisons, GOOD GRIEF -- this is teenager type behavior that mature people are going to question.  You can't stop people from talking, but you can "stop dipping your pen in the company ink".

Many companies frown upon people dating others in their own department or management chain, since this can give the appearance of favoritism or conflict of interest. If you intend to pursue the relationship, one of you may want to transfer to a different department to avoid that issue.
If that is what your co-workers were warning you about, their comments may have been reasonable.

Additional details added. The comments were focused specifically about how spending the night together in this context was an indiscretion and out of bounds. Why do they care?

My views are that private conduct between consenting adults is just that, private conduct off work. No change even in circumstances of a business trip as it's off company work time

You are entitled to your views. However, the company may not agree, and you should be aware of that when making your decisions. If you have considered that, then simply thank them for their concern and ignore them.

@Anthony others may feel that your behavior was inappropriate because it occurred at a work-related event which was presumably being paid for by the employer, thus giving the employer an interest in what occurs. Regardless of whether or not this is actually true, people will tend to assume it's true.

@barbecue Yes, but it was presumably outside office hours, on OP's free time, which is none of the employer's business. Or do business trips in the US imply being "at work" all 24 hours a day?

@TooTea Please read the last sentence of my comment.

@barbecue I did, that's basically what I'm replying to. Why would people assume it's paid work time when it's late in the evening, presumably long after all the work-related activities of the day? In my (EU-based) experience with business trips, evenings at the bar and nights at the hotel are considered my free time, not paid work time. I don't get to declare those as overtime work, for example.

@tootea When employees are traveling for work and staying in hotels paid for by work, the actions of those employees at those hotels is seen as reflecting on the reputation of the company paying for the travel.  If an employee is staying at a hotel for a work conference, and gets drunk and wanders into the lobby and urinates in the fountain, that employees actions will be seen as reflecting poorly on their employer.

@TooTea There is no black-and-white dividing line between work hours and off-hours when the entire trip is funded by the company, and in the US,  it's very common for employees traveling for work to be seen as representing their company in everything they do. Many employment contracts even have clauses specifying that their behavior off-the-clock should not reflect badly on the employer.

@barbecue I think that's a bit of a stretch. Unless a company has an entire hotel blocked off for some massive convention, bookings are typically done in the name of the traveller, not their employer; and the hotel staff will probably never know if the card used to pay for the room is personal or company-owned. Perhaps the hotel's accountant would be able to link your stay to your employer if they did a bit of detective work, but most of the staff won't know who paid for your trip.

@TooTea it's not even remotely a stretch in today's world of viral videos and social media shaming. I could easily point to multiple instances of a person behaving badly in a public place causing repercussions for their employer. There's also the whole question of vicarious liability, when an employer is held to be liable for bad acts by an employee when the employee is acting as a representative of the company.

@TooTea regardless, my original point was not about what outsiders might think, or what real liability might exist, but about what the actual co-workers thought, and why those people might think the poster's actions reflect badly on the company.
